# Find the area of ​​a triangle knowing one side and two angles.

Tags: geometry

We have given triangle $ABC$ where $AB=a$ and we also know that $\angle A=\alpha$ and $\angle B = \beta $ my question is how to find the area thereof triangle? I thing there would be useful formula $[ABC]=\frac{a*|AC|\sin\alpha}{2}$

Comment: You've got enough info to find $AC$ using the law of sines....

Comment: I've already solved this problem using theorem of sines, the area $[ABC]=\frac{a^2\sin\alpha\sin\beta}{2\sin(\alpha+\beta)}$

Comment: If one wants to be fancy, one can use the sine formula to calculate all the 3 sides of the triangle and then use Heron's formula for the area.

Comment: $$[ABC]=\frac{a^2}{\cot A + \cot B}$$

Answer (score 4):

Suggestion: Use the Law of Sines

$$\dfrac {\sin(\angle C)}{a} = \dfrac {\sin \alpha}{|BC|} = \dfrac{\sin \beta}{|AC|}$$

Comment: Nice answer amWhy as usual.

Comment: Fine dear amWhy. Thanks to God.